# Can not see variable during debugging with eclipse error

Tags: perl, testing, epic

I am using EPIC+Eclipse for perl development. When debugging perl script, I am not seeeing variables during debugging. Here is my setup.

Windows 7 64-bit

Perl 5.8.9

Eclipse

EPIC 0.5

During debugging, initially it went fine; at a later statement, I get a popup with following error message.

An internal error occurred during: "child count update".
11809

I have made changes to Cwd.pm too as described in other forums.

Any help will be highly appreciated!!!
I heard about padre too. Will it work with my activeState perl 5.8.9?

Error log shows the following exception:

http://pastebin.com/jvTMMbAt

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause. Actually there were two Cwd.pm in my perl lib. One is in lib and another is in site/lib. When modified both Cwd.pm, I am getting the correct result. Variables are coming during bebugging :)